# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "urlObject" argument must be one of type object or string. Received type function ([Function])

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, supertest

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
let chai = require('chai');
const { post } = require('../server');
//const describe = require('mocha').describe;
// const { expect } = chai;
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('API endpoints', () => {
 let api 


before(() => {
    console.log('setting up')
    api = server.listen(3000, 'localhost');
});
it('responds to /posts with status 200', done => {
    request(api)
        .post(post)
        .expect(200, done);
});
```

code im testing in server.js

```
server.post("/posts", (req, res) => {
const incomingRequest = req.body;
if (isValidPost(incomingRequest)) {
 const post = {
  name: incomingRequest.name.toString(),
  content: incomingRequest.content.toString(),
  giph: incomingRequest.gif.toString(),
  date: new Date(),
  likes: 0,
  dislikes: 0,
  laughs: 0,
  comments: [],
  //id : database.length
 };
```

im trying to test a post request, however I'm not sure im doing it correctly so this is the error im receiving
responds to /posts with status 200:
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "urlObject" argument must be one of type object or string. Received type function ([Function])